# Python `yield from`, or return a generator?

Tags: python, function, return, generator

I wrote this simple piece of code:

```
def mymap(func, *seq):
  return (func(*args) for args in zip(*seq))
```

Should I use the 'return' statement as above to return a generator, or use a 'yield from' instruction like this:

```
def mymap(func, *seq):
  yield from (func(*args) for args in zip(*seq))
```

and beyond the technical difference between 'return' and 'yield from', which is the better approach the in general case?

Comment: Just stumbled over this myself, excellent question. From the view of the caller of the function this doesn't make any difference, but I wonder what python does under the hood here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The difference is that your first `mymap` is just a usual function,
in this case a factory which returns a generator. Everything
inside the body gets executed as soon as you call the function.

```
def gen_factory(func, seq):
    """Generator factory returning a generator."""
    # do stuff ... immediately when factory gets called
    print("build generator & return")
    return (func(*args) for args in seq)
```

The second `mymap` is also a factory, but it's also a generator
itself, yielding from a self-built sub-generator inside.
Because it is a generator itself, execution of the body does
not start until the first invokation of next(generator).

```
def gen_generator(func, seq):
    """Generator yielding from sub-generator inside."""
    # do stuff ... first time when 'next' gets called
    print("build generator & yield")
    yield from (func(*args) for args in seq)
```

I think the following example will make it clearer.
We define data packages which shall be processed with functions,
bundled up in jobs we pass to the generators.

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def sqrt(a):
    return a ** 0.5

data1 = [*zip(range(1, 5))]  # [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
data2 = [(2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 1)]

job1 = (sqrt, data1)
job2 = (add, data2)
```

Now we run the following code inside an interactive shell like IPython to
see the different behavior. `gen_factory` immediately prints
out, while `gen_generator` only does so after `next()` being called.

```
gen_fac = gen_factory(*job1)
# build generator & return <-- printed immediately
next(gen_fac)  # start
# Out: 1.0
[*gen_fac]  # deplete rest of generator
# Out: [1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0]

gen_gen = gen_generator(*job1)
next(gen_gen)  # start
# build generator & yield <-- printed with first next()
# Out: 1.0
[*gen_gen]  # deplete rest of generator
# Out: [1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0]
```

To give you a more reasonable use case example for a construct
like `gen_generator` we'll extend it a little and make a coroutine
out of it by assigning yield to variables, so we can inject jobs
into the running generator with `send()`.

Additionally we create a helper function which will run all tasks
inside a job and ask as for a new one upon completion.

```
def gen_coroutine():
    """Generator coroutine yielding from sub-generator inside."""
    # do stuff... first time when 'next' gets called
    print("receive job, build generator & yield, loop")
    while True:
        try:
            func, seq = yield "send me work ... or I quit with next next()"
        except TypeError:
            return "no job left"
        else:
            yield from (func(*args) for args in seq)


def do_job(gen, job):
    """Run all tasks in job."""
    print(gen.send(job))
    while True:
        result = next(gen)
        print(result)
        if result == "send me work ... or I quit with next next()":
            break
```

Now we run `gen_coroutine`with our helper function `do_job`and two jobs.

```
gen_co = gen_coroutine()
next(gen_co)  # start
# receive job, build generator & yield, loop  <-- printed with first next()
# Out:'send me work ... or I quit with next next()'
do_job(gen_co, job1)  # prints out all results from job
# 1
# 1.4142135623730951
# 1.7320508075688772
# 2.0
# send me work... or I quit with next next()
do_job(gen_co, job2)  # send another job into generator
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
# send me work... or I quit with next next()
next(gen_co)
# Traceback ...
# StopIteration: no job left
```

To come back to your question which version is the better approach in general.
IMO something like `gen_factory` makes only sense if you need the same thing done for multiple generators you are going to create, or in cases your construction process for generators is complicated enough to justify use of a factory instead of building individual generators in place with a generator comprehension.

### Note:

The description above for the `gen_generator` function (second `mymap`) states
"it *is* a generator itself". That is a bit vague and technically not 
really correct, but facilitates reasoning about the differences of the functions
in this tricky setup where `gen_factory` also returns a generator, namely that
one built by the generator comprehension inside.

In fact **any** function (not only those from this question with generator comprehensions inside!) with a `yield` inside, upon invocation, just
*returns* a generator object which gets constructed out of the function body.

`type(gen_coroutine)  # function`
`gen_co = gen_coroutine(); type(gen_co)  # generator`

So the whole action we observed above for `gen_generator` and `gen_coroutine` 
takes place within these generator objects, functions with `yield` inside have spit out before.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is: return a generator. It's more fast:

```sh
marco@buzz:~$ python3.9 -m pyperf timeit --rigorous --affinity 3 --value 6 --loops=4096 -s '
a = range(1000)

def f1():
    for x in a:
        yield x

def f2():
    return f1()

' 'tuple(f2())'
........................................
Mean +- std dev: 72.8 us +- 5.8 us
marco@buzz:~$ python3.9 -m pyperf timeit --rigorous --affinity 3 --value 6 --loops=4096 -s '
a = range(1000)

def f1():
    for x in a:
        yield x

def f2():
    yield from f1()

' 'tuple(f2())'
........................................
WARNING: the benchmark result may be unstable
* the standard deviation (12.6 us) is 10% of the mean (121 us)

Try to rerun the benchmark with more runs, values and/or loops.
Run 'python3.9 -m pyperf system tune' command to reduce the system jitter.
Use pyperf stats, pyperf dump and pyperf hist to analyze results.
Use --quiet option to hide these warnings.

Mean +- std dev: 121 us +- 13 us
```

If you read [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), the main reason for the introduction of `yield from` is to use a part of the code of a generator for another generator, without having to duplicate the code or change the API:

> The rationale behind most of the semantics presented above stems from
>   the desire to be able to refactor generator code. It should be
>   possible to take a section of code containing one or more yield
>   expressions, move it into a separate function (using the usual
>   techniques to deal with references to variables in the surrounding
>   scope, etc.), and call the new function using a yield from expression.

[Source](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#the-refactoring-principle)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the version with `yield from` because it makes it easier to handle exceptions and context managers.

Take the example of a generator expression for the lines of a file:

```py
def with_return(some_file):
    with open(some_file, 'rt') as f:
        return (line.strip() for line in f)

for line in with_return('/tmp/some_file.txt'):
    print(line)
```

The `return` version raises a `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` since the file is not open anymore after the `return` statement.

On the other hand, the `yield from` version works as expected:

```py
def with_yield_from(some_file):
    with open(some_file, 'rt') as f:
        yield from (line.strip() for line in f)


for line in with_yield_from('/tmp/some_file.txt'):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most important difference (I don't know if `yield from generator` is optimized) is that the context is different for `return` and `yield from`.

```py
[ins] In [1]: def generator():
         ...:     yield 1
         ...:     raise Exception
         ...:

[ins] In [2]: def use_generator():
         ...:     return generator()
         ...:

[ins] In [3]: def yield_generator():
         ...:     yield from generator()
         ...:

[ins] In [4]: g = use_generator()

[ins] In [5]: next(g); next(g)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3d9500a8db9f> in <module>
----> 1 next(g); next(g)

<ipython-input-1-b4cc4538f589> in generator()
      1 def generator():
      2     yield 1
----> 3     raise Exception
      4

Exception:

[ins] In [6]: g = yield_generator()

[ins] In [7]: next(g); next(g)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3d9500a8db9f> in <module>
----> 1 next(g); next(g)

<ipython-input-3-3ab40ecc32f5> in yield_generator()
      1 def yield_generator():
----> 2     yield from generator()
      3

<ipython-input-1-b4cc4538f589> in generator()
      1 def generator():
      2     yield 1
----> 3     raise Exception
      4

Exception:
```

Answer (score 0):

*Generators* use `yield`, *functions* use `return`.

*Generators* are generally used in `for` loops for repeatedly iterating over the values *automatically provided by a generator*, but may be used also in another context, e. g. in *list()* function to create list - again from values *automatically provided by a generator*.

*Functions* are called to provide *return value*, *only one* value for every call.

Answer (score -7):

Really it depends on the situation. `yield` is mainly suited to cases where you just want to iterate over the returned values and then manipulate them. `return` is mainly suited for when you want to store all of the values that your function has generated in memory rather than just iterate over them once. Do note that you can only iterate over  a generator (what yield returns) once, there are some algorithms which this is definitely not suited for.

Comment: Although accepted, this does not address the core issue, which has nothing to do with 'storing all the values' or 'iterating over the returned values'. I would expect an answer with either a stylistic argument or some benchmarks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the case in the question. This would be applicable for deciding whether to `yield` values or `return` a list of them, not whether to `return` or `yield from` another generator.